# How to extract all elements after last underscore in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with a column I am trying to extract information from. To give you an example, the column is a combination of 4 foreign keys which could look like this:

Ex 1: 12345-123-12345-4

Ex 2: 5678-4321-123-12

I am trying to extract the last piece of the string, in this case the 4 & 12. Any idea on how I can do this?

I've tried the following:

```
df.withColumn("result", sf.split(sf.col("column_to_split"), '\_')[1])\
  .withColumn("result", sf.col("result").cast('integer'))
```

However, the result for double digit values is null, and it only returns an integer for single digits (0-9)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share more of your code? What is sf ?

Comment: Sorry, sf is the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
```

Comment: I posted an answer, showing how to split a string containing a serial number to get the last digit. If it doesn't work, let us know what error message you're getting

Comment: check `substring_index('column_to_split', '_', -1)` http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index

Comment: Thanks everyone! Most of these solutions worked on the first try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **spark2.4**,You should use `element_at` `-1` on your `array` after `split`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
df.withColumn("result", sf.element_at(sf.split("column_to_split","\-"),-1).cast("int")).show()

+-----------------+------+
|  column_to_split|result|
+-----------------+------+
|12345-123-12345-4|     4|
| 5678-4321-123-12|    12|
+-----------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Mohammad's answer is very clean and a nice solution. However if you need a solution for Spark versions < 2.4, you can utilise the reverse string functionality and take the first element, reverse it back and turn into an Integer, f.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['column_to_split'] = ["12345-123-12345-4", "5678-4321-123-12"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

df.withColumn("result", 
              f.reverse(f.split(f.reverse("column_to_split"), "-")[0]). \
               cast(t.IntegerType())).show(2, False)

+-----------------+------+
|column_to_split  |result|
+-----------------+------+
|12345-123-12345-4|4     |
|5678-4321-123-12 |12    |
+-----------------+------+
```

Comment: It works Richard, but i think the use of second reverse is unecessary. U could just do one reverse on the array and take first element.
`df.withColumn("result", sf.reverse(sf.split("column_to_split","\-"))[0]).show()`

Comment: Yes that is certainly another way :) I'm pretty sure there are hundreds of ways to do this, from using `regexp_extract` (probably the most efficient way) to UDFs. It probably depends on what the developer is most comfortable with, unless there are other requirements on time/versioning/architecture/etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the last digits of the serial number above:

```
serial_no = '12345-123-12345-4'
last_digit = serial_no.split('-')[-1]
print(last_digit)
```

So in your case, try:

```
df.withColumn("result", int(sf.col("column_to_split").split('-')[-1]))
```

If it doesn't work, please share the result.

Answer (score 0):

Adding up another ways:

You can use **`.regexp_extract()`** (or) **`.substring_index()`** function also:

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-----------------+
#|  column_to_split|
#+-----------------+
#|12345-123-12345-4|
#| 5678-4321-123-12|
#+-----------------+
df.withColumn("result",regexp_extract(col("column_to_split"),"([^-]+$)",1).cast("int")).\
withColumn("result1",substring_index(col("column_to_split"),"-",-1).cast("int")).\
show()
#+-----------------+------+-------+
#|  column_to_split|result|result1|
#+-----------------+------+-------+
#|12345-123-12345-4|     4|      4|
#| 5678-4321-123-12|    12|     12|
#+-----------------+------+-------+
```